# VS2017 WPF Designer Exception TransformToVisual

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, designer

Since we upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, the WPF designer of our main window sometimes shows "An exception was thrown" with the information below.

It seems to happen after compiling or ending a debug session and it goes away upon clicking in the xaml code.

Does anyone know how I can get more detailed information ? The Stack Trace only leads to the "TransformToVisual" method, but we never call this method in our own code:

> InvalidOperationException: The specified Visual and this Visual do not
>   share a common ancestor, so there is no valid transformation between
>   the two Visuals.
>
> Stacktrace: at System.Windows.Media.Visual.TransformToVisual(Visual
>   visual)
>
> InnerException: None